# font abandon diferente na web

Tags: html, css, front-end, css-font-face

bom dia tudo bem com vocês?
Seguinte...
Eu baixei e instalei a font Abandon e no photoshop ela fica ótima, aí, fui lançar no html com o comando

```
@font-face {
    font-family: abandon;
    src: url('..//fonts/AbandoN.ttf');
    /**titulo**/
}
```

e quando chamo no html fica diferente, a textura(que é o melhor da fonte) da font fica diferente, quase sumindo...
eu quero deixar a fonte no html igual a como fica no photoshop...o que eu posso fazer para consertar?

Comment: Tente aumentar o tamanho da letra. Estou achando que você precisa digitar `abadon` com A maiúsculo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é mais simples do que parece... Link para download da font caso alguém quera testar **Font Abandon** https://www.dafont.com/pt/abandon2.font

Eu usei a font em um `<H1>` e olha como renderizou nos Browsers. **A tag `<h1>` no Chrome já vem com BOLD por default, ai a font ficou ruim!**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> Já quando eu tirei o **BOLD** e deixei com `font-weight: normal;` a fonte renderizou perfeita no Chrome!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse foi o código que usei

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'abandonregular';
    src: url('AbandoN.ttf');
    src: url('AbandoN.ttf')  format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1 {
 font-family: 'abandonregular';
 font-weight: normal;

 font-size: 150px;
}

p {
 font-family: 'abandonregular';
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
```

> **[Aqui tem um link com a fonte funcionando e renderizando bem](http://encurtador.com.br/BCI69)**

Comment: deu certo!! perfeito!!! muito obrigado!!!

Comment: @HoracioJ. legal que resolveu! Tmj! 

Comment: eu que agradeço!! grande abraço e mais uma vez, muito obrigado!!! tmj